# GE side-by-side refrigerator, slow water flow, hollowed out ice cubes. Which solenoid valve(s

Tags: repair, appliances, refrigerator

Our 2011 GE (Monogram!) side-by-side  has been losing water pressure to the door dispenser for a couple of years, and now slowed to a trickle, as well as small hollowed-out ice cubes.    The GE MWF water filter is not the issue because the problem persists even after the filter is removed and the bypass plug installed in its place.

This model has more than one electric solenoid valve. It has the typical water inlet solenoid valve, and bolted onto the back of that, a second  double solenoid valve, which seems to send water from the filter outlet side down to both or either of the door dispenser or the icemaker in the freezer compartment.

From what I am reading, the intake solenoid valve which receives water from the copper in-line saddle valve in the home, and sends it to the water filter head, is the most likely candidate for failure and replacement.

Here is a photo of the entire solenoid valve assembly, including both valves. 
[image]

Note that the valve on the right side (with the orange inlet port) is the more common water inlet valve.

The simpler water inlet solenoid valve (on the right side) is much less expensive than the entire assembly, that includes separate solenoids on the left side that route water down into the appliance for the dispenser and ice maker.

I'd hate to buy the solenoid valve on the inlet side and find that the problem was in the larger double solenoid valve.

Can an experienced DIY or repair person comment on which valve solenoid to purchase?

I have also read that occasionally the filter socket or filter head has some call it, can also go bad, although this seems  much less likely to me.

Diagnostic tips would be much appreciated!

(Because the refrigerator is a built-in model, the solenoid valves are much harder to access in the machine compartment above, and you can't easily detach the water supply line and have water flow into a bucket.)

Thanks!

Comment: can you test the solenoid's operation with a DC supply?

Comment: Are you sure it is the solenoid? Saddle valves are a very common failure point. If your connection to the plumbing is via a saddle valve I would check that first because the hole is quite small and they do plug up. A replacement valve will be much cheaper than a solenoid.

Comment: Hollowed out ice cubes means they are being ejected too soon.  It could be an airflow issue, a freezer performance issue, setting the freezer not cold enough, or an icemaker timing issue.

Comment: Ed Beal, you are the man! Spot on advice. I disconnected the copper 1/4" supply line under the built-in refer, and checked water flow to the appliance first.

Ed nailed it. No need to buy any solenoid on my 6-yr old Monogram. The issue was a blocked crappy saddle valve under the floor (in crawl!) which restricts flow.

I am removing the lousy saddle valve (those should be banned!), and popping on a 1/2" push-on x 1/4" compression angle stop (Sharkbite etc.), and reconnect 1/4" copper line. I'll post result tomorrow. Anticipating great flow. House water pressure is aces.

Thanks Ed.